# Browser responses with 502 containing a single 'date' header

Tags: http, nginx, networking, webserver, jetty

I'm using `nginx` server (as a reverse proxy). In some rare cases, while issuing hundreds of `HTTP GET` request to the server, the client receives `502` response while containing only the `date` header.

I'm using default `nginx` settings so configuration is not the issue.

I wonder, where is the `502` response is coming from? The `nginx`? The server? Or, maybe, it is a some kind of a default browser's behaviour?

**Update:**
While receiving the `502` error I can't find any logged information about the error. I've checked both of the files, the `api_access.log` and the `api_error.log`

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the nginx configuration? The 502 means bad gateway and is very likely sent by nginx as a reponse because something crashed on the backend. But this will be printed in the nginxs error log. Usually located in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like HTTP/2, which only includes a header (request or response) if it's delta indicates a change from the prior request.

In other words, in HTTP/2, if the header is the same as the previous request it's not included again.

Obviously the `Date` header changes quite frequently, but most other headers do not.

If you are using proxy_pass, and talking to HTTP/1.x behind nginx, you'll need to configure your proxy_pass properly for your situation (Lots of answers on https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/nginx with details on what you would need to do)

Comment: Can you back up your statement, regarding the headers omission, with official RFC specs? As I know HTTP is a stateless protocol so knowing which headers were not changed from the previous call contradicts the HTTP statelessness principle.

Answer (score 1):

A 502 error is the NGINX proxy saying it received an incorrect response from the server.

You might want to do a manual 'get' with the same data as the call with the 502 error in Postman, to see if you can emulate the error.

If you cannot emulate it, the problem is most likely that the server cannot keep up with your requests, you can check if there are some optimisations you can do (client or server side), hundreds of request in general is not ideal (this could be a single request?).